# How to correct docker in makefile which requires at least 1 argument for remove all containers command

Tags: docker, makefile, containers, rm

The docker command "`docker container rm $(docker ps -aq) -f`" works fine from the command line.  However, when I try to run it from a makefile using the following target ("`remove_all_containers`")...

```
remove_all_containers:
       docker container rm $(docker ps -aq) -f
```

I get the error message:

```
host_name$ make remove_all_containers
docker container rm  -f
"docker container rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker container rm --help'.

Usage:  docker container rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers
make: *** [remove_all_containers] Error 1
```

Clearly, when executed from within the makefile, the "`docker ps`" command is not being properly being properly executed in a way where its results can be collected and passed into the "`container rm`" command.

**My Question:** How do I get the "`docker ps`" command to run correctly from within the makefile and pass its results correctly into the "`docker rm`" command, also within the **makefile**?

Thanks, in advance, for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a second `$` in your recipe:

```
remove_all_containers:
       docker container rm $$(docker ps -aq) -f
#                           ^
```

The single `$` is expanded as a makefile variable when the makefile is parsed.  It expands to blank.  Make therefore passes `docker container rm  -f` to your shell.   The second `$` sign causes make to expand `$$` to `$`, and it will pass `docker container rm $(docker ps -aq) -f` to bash, which I'm guessing is what you want.

Notice, if you put the `shell` in there as @EricMd proposed, it will run a shell command, but that command will be run at Makefile read time, as opposed to the time that the recipe is executed.   If the `docker ps -aq` command is dependent on any other artifacts of your build it would not work.

Comment: I appreciate, both, your correct answer and your detailed explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Sounds like you don't have any containers in docker to remove. I sometimes use a different syntax for this scenario:

```
remove_all_containers:
       docker container ls -aq | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container rm -f
```

The xargs syntax will not run `docker container rm` if there are no containers to delete.

Comment: `--no-run-if-empty` does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/), `docker ps -a` should list all containers.

You obtained this message `"docker container rm" requires at least 1 argument` certainly because you forgot to prepend the command at stake with Make's `shell` builtin:

```
remove_all_containers:
       docker container rm $(shell docker ps -aq) -f
```

Note also that the `docker ps` admits a filtering feature: the online doc  describes the various flavors of the corresponding [`-f` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering).

For example, below are three Bash alias examples that can be useful to (*i*) stop all containers, (*ii*) remove all stopped containers; and (*iii*) remove dangling images−that would be tagged as `<none>` when doing `docker images ls`:

```
alias docker-stop='docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)'
alias docker-clean='docker rm $(docker ps -a -q -f status=exited)'
alias docker-purge='docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)'
```

Comment: The `-a` option includes all containers, not just the running ones.

Answer (score 0):

I tested for 2 way follow bellow answer:

```
remove_all_containers:
   docker container rm $$(docker ps -aq) -f


remove_all_containers:
   docker container rm $(shell docker ps -aq) -f
```